# Google Sheets: Copy cell from one sheet to another if cell is "Yes" but wrong info is shown if user changes mind

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that I want to copy info from "potential_presentations" sheet into "finalized_presentations" if "Finalized" column is a "Yes". The biggest issue is that comments will be shifted if users later change their mind and don't want to present. This is because the comments are typed manually next to the importrange formula. Lastly there are a few minor issues such as hyperlink in importrange not showing up and no one cannot hyperlink cells with importrange.

Current formula: `=query(IMPORTRANGE("14Sjw_S-ZejOJMxTKUSsjS_iB17g8gdklIYrUNTO-aWI","potential_presentations!A2:Z"),"select Col3 where Col1 = 'Yes'")`

Edit: I have a sheet named "potential_presentations" where users fill in their info and if their presentation is finalized, they will mark "Yes" in column "Finalized?". My query-importrange formula below will move all user's info who marked "Yes" into a different sheet named "finalized_presentations" where there are additional columns such as column "comments" for users to add. The problem is that if a user changes their mind and marks "No" in column "Finalized", then the info will not match up anymore in sheet "finalized_presentations" and the column "Comments". Please see the Google Sheet link as an example. I even created a quick [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbylxI8kGLA) explaining my issue.

[Google Sheet Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14Sjw_S-ZejOJMxTKUSsjS_iB17g8gdklIYrUNTO-aWI/edit#gid=2054679966).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry; I don't understand what **exactly** is your problem. Would you please also edit your question to show what you have tried to resolve this issue, and also summarise the research that you did before posting the question.  Lastly, would you please include, in the body of the question, sample data as well as example of a successful outcome.

Comment: @Tedinoz Sorry about that. I added more info in the edit.

Comment: Thank you for the YouTube, but please regard it as an optional extra only; be 100% sure that your question includes **all** of the information that you cover in the video.

Comment: I'm not sure how these relate specifically to your scenario, but did you include the following in your research: [How to transfer comments when transferring data from one table to another in Google Sheet with the QUERY+IMPORTRANGE function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70921756/1330560) OR [Preserve associated row data while using importRange in the destination sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67847516/1330560) OR [How to prevent erase of cells in another Google Sheet file with Query/importrange](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57014481/1330560)

Comment: @Tedinoz, Thanks. I did my research yesterday but did not come across the links you sent. I guess I need to create a script. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution. Used Appscript from a video I found on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5sK5mngU2Ho&t=1122s). I modified the code to prevent duplicates!

```
function onOpen(e) {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  ui.createMenu(' Automation Tools')
    .addItem('Move "Yes" to another sheet', 'moveRows')
    .addToUi(); 
}; 
 
function moveRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ENTER_GOOGLE_SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const targetLastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  let sortRange = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 1, lastRow, 4);
 
  Logger.log(lastRow);
  let targetCounter = 1;
 
  for (var i = 1; i <= sortRange.length; i++) {
    let name = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    let id = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue(); // Assuming ID is in column 2
    console.log(i + " - " + name);
 
    if (name == "Yes") {
      // Check if the row already exists in the target sheet based on the unique ID
      let rowExists = false;
      for (let j = 2; j <= targetLastRow + targetCounter; j++) {
        let targetID = targetSheet.getRange(j, 2).getValue();
        if (id === targetID) {
          rowExists = true;
          break;
        }
      }
 
      if (!rowExists) {
        let rowValues = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 4).getValues();
        targetSheet.getRange(targetLastRow + targetCounter, 1, 1, 4).setValues(rowValues);
        targetCounter++;
      } else {
        console.log("Duplicate row found and skipped.");
      }
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: well done for posting this. Sometimes code-only answers don't allow users to quickly identify, understand and visualise the key parts of the solution. Consider adding screen shots of sample data (potential_presentations) and the result (finalized_presentations). Consider also a brief narrative of the essential logic/commands/structure of the script.  On a tangent, how did you handle the link?